# How to realize a counter in scrapy pipeline?

Tags: python, scrapy

**Pipelines.py**

```
class DotabuffPipeline(object):

def open_spider(self, spider):
    self.match_dict = {}

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    ID = item['matchID']
    if ID in self.match_dict:
        self.match_dict[ID] =  self.match_dict[ID] + 1
        if self.match_dict[ID]==5:
            return item
    else:
        self.match_dict[ID] = 1
```

**firstspider.py**

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
import json
from dotabuff.items import DotabuffItem

class DotaSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "dotaspider"
    allow_domains = ['www.dotabuff.com']
    start_urls = []
    with open('spiders/Steam.json','r') as f:
        steam_data = json.load(f)
        f.close
    steam_members = steam_data['members']
    for member in steam_members:
        url = 'http://www.dotabuff.com/players/%s/matches?page=1' %str(member-76561197960265728)
        start_urls.append(url)

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'http://www.dotabuff.com/players/\d+/matches\?page=\d+')), callback="parse_item", follow= True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        matches = sel.xpath('//td[@class="cell-large"]/a/@href').extract()
        for match in matches:
            item = DotabuffItem()
            match = match.split('/')[-1]
            item['matchID'] = match
            yield item
```

I scrapy some match numbers from www.dotabuff.com, and i have five steam id in a json. I want to find out the matches we five played together. So i define a dict used as a counter to count the number of appearance.But it doesn't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 150, in
maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "e:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\xlib\pydispatch\robustapply.py", l
ine 57, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "e:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\extensions\feedexport.py", line 19
3, in item_scraped
    slot.exporter.export_item(item)
  File "e:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\exporters.py", line 111, in export
_item
    itemdict = dict(self._get_serialized_fields(item))
  File "e:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\exporters.py", line 63, in _get_se
rialized_fields
    field_iter = six.iterkeys(item)
  File "e:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 593, in iterkeys
    return d.iterkeys(**kw)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'
```

Comment: have you looked at `counter` in `collections`  https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs for pipelines in scrapy [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html), it says

> This method is called for every item pipeline component and must
>   either return a dict with data, Item (or any descendant class) object
>   or raise a DropItem exception.

Your process_item method doesn't obey this rule and can return `None`, which is not iterable.